# How is disposing Windsor in Application_End different from doing it in HttpApplication.Dispose?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have an ASP.NET MVC project where I'm using Castle.Windsor. This gets set up in the Global.asax file and sits attached to the HttpApplication. Until recently I had been disposing of the container in the Dispose method :

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    Container.Dispose();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

But while debugging over the last few days I've noticed (typically the second time I run the VS.NET development server) I'm getting this error :

> Scope was already disposed. This is most likely a bug in the calling code.

I found vague references on the castle-project-users Google group to putting the Container.Dispose() call in Application_End instead. So I've done this and now don't appear to be getting the errors anymore...at least so far.

I don't understand what's different though. Are there situations where Dispose is called but Application_End isn't? If that's the case, how is that disposed application still being used on the next request?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there situations where Dispose is called but Application_End isn't?

Yes.

> If that's the case, how is that disposed application still being used on the next request?

It isn't.

Asp.Net will create multiple instances of your HttpApplication derived class and use them to process requests but it will only call Application_Start and Application_End once, period.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on an old issue I had. I think the confusion arose from the fact that we had a Container property on the HttpApplication which was being populated in the *constructor* (not Application_Start) and yet seemingly shared amongst all the instances of the application. When disposed for one it seemed to be disposed for all.